# Integration testing with spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a problem :

I have two component A and B (Two wars ) :

A for storage(Neo4J) and B for search(Elasticsearch).

the communication between the components is managed by Spring Integration using HTTP Inbound/Outbound .

Here is MY configuration files for spring integration : 
Server A (Storage)

```
<int:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.UriPathHandlerMapping"/>

 <int:gateway id="searchGateway"
             service-interface="xxxxx.IAuditSearchService"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway auto-startup="true"
                           request-channel="sendRequest"
                           url="http://localhost:8081/B/api/es"
                           extract-request-payload="true"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="searchResult"
                          request-payload-type="xxxxx.SearchResult"
                          path="/api/searchResult"
                          supported-methods="POST"/>

<int:object-to-json-transformer auto-startup="true"
                                id="objectToJson" input-channel="searchRequest"
                                output-channel="sendRequest">
</int:object-to-json-transformer>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="searchReply"
                                auto-startup="true"
                                id="jsonToObject" output-channel="searchResult"
                                type="xxxxxxxx.SearchResult">
</int:json-to-object-transformer>

<int:channel id="searchRequest"/>
<int:channel id="sendRequest"/>
<int:channel id="searchReply"/>
<int:channel id="searchResult"/>
```

In the other side : 
Server B :

```
    <int:annotation-config/>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.UriPathHandlerMapping"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="searchRequest"
                          reply-channel="searchReply"
                          path="/api/es"
                          request-payload-type="xxxx.AuditChange"
                          supported-methods="POST"/>


<int:gateway id="searchGateway"
             service-interface="xxxx.IAbSearchResult"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway auto-startup="true"
                           request-channel="searchResult"
                           url="http://localhost:9080/A/api/searchResult"/>


<int:json-to-object-transformer id="jsonToObject" input-channel="searchRequest"
                                type="xxxxxx.AuditChange"/>
<int:object-to-json-transformer id="objectToJson" input-channel="searchReply" output-channel="searchResult"/>

<int:channel id="searchRequest"/>
<!--<int:channel id="esDelete"/>-->
<int:channel id="searchReply"/>
<int:channel id="searchResult"/>
```

My question :

I want to do an integration test from the server A to Server B To server A .

What's the best strategy ? 
It's possible to do it without mocking ? 
It's possible to do it without starting the servers ? (Servers A and B down)

Best Regards
Nabil Belakbir

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure is this you want for integration tests.

You can use Spring mvc test framework to test inbound gateway without starting up any server.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { /*omitted*/ })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HttpInboundGatewayIntegrationTests {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInboundGateway()
        throws Exception {
    //

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/searchResult").
            param("aParam", aParam).
            param("anotherParam",anotherParam)).
            andExpect(status().isForbidden());
}
```

But if you want to test the gateway only, you'd better sperate the spring configuration into different xmls(a-http-gateway.xml for the InboundGateway alone, for example).

On the other hand, A server has to be started up for test outbound gateway without stubbing or mocking. Maybe you are interested in https://github.com/dreamhead/moco, it's a simple framework to stub http server.

Comment: Thanks for your response . My problem is that Server A and Server B are comlettely separated . SO Spring MVC test will allow me to test the InboundGateway without starting the server A . I can do this also by testing the Gateway directelly . SO the problem is that when the server A will try to reach the server B . In this case the server B must be started or mocked . I didn't find otehr way to do this properly . Thanks also for moco It can be helpfull in my case

Answer (score 1):

See the [testing examples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples) and [advanced testing examples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/advanced-testing-examples) for ideas about how to test flows independently.